# vb.net + Convert a SQL database to a DBF database without provider, using text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, migration, dbf

I work with vb.net

I have a sqlServer database and i need to migrate to a DBF database.

I know that a dbf file sctructure is a hexadecimal text file.

I want to generate this file without a provider...building this file with this hexadecimal structure.

Somebody here already did it???

I hope you undestand what i said.

Thanks by the attention.

Comment: By DBF, do you mean you need to use dBase format?

Comment: yes..i have a sqlserver database and i want to migrate to this, but i dont want to use a provider...i want to build the file structure.

Comment: A dbf file is *not* a "hexadecimal text file". It's a binary file with a documented format. See [wotsit](http://wotsit.org) for a definition of .dbf files.

Comment: You are  right about it, its a binary file...i dont express myself correctly. I solve my problem. If somebody in the future need to do something like this, this link can help: [dbf_link](http://www.dbf2002.com/dbf-file-format.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have SQl Server I would use SSIS to do the task. You can directly create a dBase file using an ODBC connection. Although why anyone would want to go back to dBase when they already have a SQl Server database is a mystery to me.

Comment: to use new data on a legacy system perhaps?

Comment: Yes zespri... And its not unsual...The costumer has his own system and dont want to change it